# loading json to dict in python and accessing data

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON file with data from two trees in it I want to use in a script:

```
{"trees":{
"tree1":{"name":"tree1","tt1":"1","ul":"2"},
"tree2":{"name":"tree2","tt2":"1","ul":"2"}
 }   }
```

I try this

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:
     data = json.load(data_file)

print ("ulink of tree2 is %s" % trees['tree2']['ul'])
```

but it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "open-json.py", line 10, in <module>
print ("ulink of tree2 is %s" % trees['tree2']['ul'])
NameError: name 'trees' is not defined
```

what am I doing wrong? This keeps on eluding me.

After the first answer:
thanks! I added your sentence and it works (but I do not understand why exactly):

script is now

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)
trees = data['trees']
for keys,values in trees.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)
print "yoyo"
print ("ulink of tree2 is %s" % trees['tree2']['ul'])
```

Now no more errors:

```
tree1
{u'ul': u'2', u'tt1': u'1'}
tree2
{u'tt2': u'1', u'ul': u'2'}
yoyo
ulink of tree2 is 2
```

simplyfied the json, by the way to

```
{"trees":{
"tree1":{"tt1":"1","ul":"2"},
"tree2":{"tt2":"1","ul":"2"}
 }   }
```

What I I don't understand is

- why all the u characters in the answer to for keys,values in trees.irmes ....
- why can't I just do

  trees = json.load(data_file)

in stead of

```
data = json.load(data_file)
trees = data['trees']
```

but its prgressing, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `trees` be an array? Also, read your error. This one is pretty self-explanatory, but if it isn't, just search around with query = name of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You called your variable `data`, not `trees`. `trees` is a key in the `data` dictionary; perhaps you wanted to create a new `trees` variable with that dictionary?

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
     data = json.load(data_file)

trees = data['trees']
print ("ulink of tree2 is %s" % trees['tree2']['ul'])
```